# window.decorView.rootWindowInsets return null

Tags: android

I am trying to draw over notch and want to manage screen view. If there is notch available then it'll be set otherwise not here is the code written in onCreate() method this works fine.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        window.attributes.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode =
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        hasNotch = true
    }
```

Now need to manage my control and want to get **safeInsetTop** but **window.decorView.rootWindowInsets** return always **null**. I tried my code to put under **oncreate()**, **onResume()** and **onAttachedToWindow()** but from all this area I am getting null. I even tried to put code under runnable with delay time but no success. I don't know what the best way

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be it's too late but I explain almost same problem. I have BottomSheetDialogFragment, where I can't achieve

```
dialog?.window?.decorView?.rootWindowInsets
```

It was null in onCreate, onStart and or even in onResume. then I just override  onCreateDialog function like this

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return object : BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), theme) {
        override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
            super.onAttachedToWindow()
            onDialogAttachedToWindow()
        }
    }
}
...

override fun onDialogAttachedToWindow() {
    dialog?.safeInsetTop // here it is not null
}
```

And safeInsetTop property is:

```
    val Dialog.safeInsetTop: Int?
    get() = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        window?.decorView?.rootWindowInsets?.displayCutout?.safeInsetTop?.orDefault()
    } else {
        null
    }
```